# explanation for matrix multiplication code

Tags: python-3.x

Can anyone explain what's going on in the line that defines 'c' here? I think I understand it but I want to make sure I really know what's going on rather than just memorizing the operation. It creates a matrix filled with 0's, c = ([0 0 0 0], [0 0 0 0], [0 0 0 0]). Why does it create a nested list rather than just a single list?

```
def mmult(a, b):
    nrowa = len(a)  # get number of rows and columns in a and b
    ncola = len(a[0])
    nrowb = len(b)
    ncolb = len(b[0])
    if ncola != nrowb:   # is multiplication possible?
        return None  # if not, bail out!
    c = [[0] * ncolb for i in range(nrowa)]
```

Comment: `[x for i in range(nrowa)]` creates a list containing `nrowa` number of `x`s. `x` in this case is `[0] * ncolb`.

Comment: Do you know what `[0] * ncolb` means?

Comment: @Scott Hunter I'm a little confused on that. ncolb should be an integer value '3' here in the case that the matrices input are 4x4. So to me this reads as [0] * 3, which is performed 4 times. I guess I think the output should be [0 0 0 0].

Comment: Sounds like you think `[0]*3` = `0*3` = `0`, when in fact `[0]*3` = `[0,0,0]`.

Comment: @ScottHunter There it is. That's exactly what I had wrong, very new to python. Thank you!